# JLPT N3 Practice Grammar 1...かた

Tags: jlpt

From #27 of 日本語能力試験３級の模擬試験　-文法１- (http://jlpt.u-biq.org/3g1.html)

> Question: よやく（　　）が わかりません。
>
> A) かた　　B) のかた　　　C) しかた　　　D) のしかた

Why is the answer D?

Comment: ...That lack of kanji confused me. I was sure よやく was a typo for ようやく and none of the given choices made any sense to me.

Comment: @oals me too lols

Answer (score 7):

> 「よやく（　　）が わかりません。」
>
> A) かた　　B) のかた　　　C) しかた　　　D) のしかた

So, the finished sentence should clearly mean:

> "I do not know how to make a reservation/appointment."

To say "how to + (verb) + (object)", we use:

> 「Object + **の** + Verb in 連用形{れんようけい} (continuative form) + 方{かた}」

Among the four choices given, only D) のしかた fits this form.  「し」 is the 連用形 of the verb「する」.

「よやく**を**する」 = "to make a reservation/appointment"  **The 「を」 changes to 「の」 in the "how to ~~" form.**

B) のかた does not have the verb 「し」.

C) しかた does not have 「の」.

A) かた is just out of the question.  It has neither 「の」 nor 「し」.

Other examples:

「ラーメン**の**食{た}べ方」"how to eat ramen"  「食べ」 is the 連用形 of「食べる」.

「チーズケーキ**の**作{つく}り方」 "how to make cheesecake"  「作り」 is the 連用形 of 「作る」.

Comment: Isn't 方 here pronounced ほう? I think the かた pronounciation is only used for the formal form of 人. ほう is used in situations like 方がいい, right?

Comment: @Sweeper The 方 in 「連用形verb+方」 is pronounced かた. 方 is read かた in eg やり[方]{かた} (how to do/way of doing), [母方]{ははかた} (mother's side), 山田様[方]{かた} (c/o Mr Yamada), がた in 先生[方]{がた} (teachers), 源氏[方]{がた} (the Genji side), 明け[方]{がた} (toward daybreak), ３割[方]{がた} (about 30%) -- basically "noun (form)+[方]{かた/がた}"